# Scroll View Edit - can I edit it outside of the view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios5, view, scroll

I'm a newbie here,

While editing scroll view contents on XCode 4's storyboard, you have to drag back and forth to "peek" and edit contents withint the view controller of iphone screen size.

Is there a way to directly edit scroll view content outside, so I don't have to constantly shift is carefully back and forth? Drying me crazy now :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag the scroll view content (which should be a single UIView or its subclass) out of the scroll view by selecting in the view hierarchy tree on the left of the storyboard editor (should be the only view that is a subview of the scroll view) and dragging it to, say, the top of the list to be on the same level (leftmost) as the root view (which should be the topmost item in that hierarchy). Then, you can select your content view. It should appear in the storyboard. When you are done editing it, drag it back below the scroll view in the view hierarchy list (it becomes the scroll view's content view at that point).

Comment: Thanks, tried a few options and found that dragging is tedious... Eventually, I just went to the property menu and edit Y offset for the view, turns out easier than dragging with a mouse. :)